# как поставить в столбик точки в слайдере slick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, slider-slick.js

сделал слайдер для товара, по центру одна большая картинка, а сбоку слева пять маленьких, кликнув на которые большая картинка менялась на них. так вот, нужно сделать так, чтобы эти маленькие картинки были в столбик.пробовал как обычно:

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
```

но видимо у slick слайдера стоит какое-то значение из-за которого не получается так сделать. знает кто-нибудь как оно называется или может быть есть другой способ решения?
HTML:

```
<div class="product-slider">
          <div class="product__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-size 1.jpg" alt="boosted в руках"></div>
          <div class="product__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-remote 2.jpg" alt="пульт от boosted"></div>
          <div class="product__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-floater 2.jpg" alt="boosted низ"></div>
          <div class="product__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-deck 2.jpg" alt="boosted верх"></div>
          <div class="product__img"><img src="img/boosted hero 2.jpg" alt="boosted сбоку"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-slider__nav">
          <div class="product-nav__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-size 2.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="product-nav__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-remote 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="product-nav__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-floater 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="product-nav__img"><img src="img/boosted-mini-s-deck 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="product-nav__img"><img src="img/boosted hero 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.product-slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        asNavFor: '.product-slider__nav'
      });
      $('.product-slider__nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        asNavFor: '.product-slider',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        variableWidth: true,
      })
    });
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
.product
  margin-top: 190px
  position: relative
.product-slider
  width: 470px
  &__nav
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column-reverse
введите сюда код
введите сюда код
```